# DocuSign API how to get Integrator Key

Tags: api, docusignapi

Just signed up to Docu Sign Sandbox following the instructions in their docs but when I go to the admin > Api and keys there is no option to create an Integrator Key. It just tells me I don't have any, with no button allowing me to create one.

has anyone had this happen?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a bug in the system where that option is missing. It is still available if you use the top right dropdown and "Switch to Classic." From there you can go to Preferences --> API and generate an integrator key. Detailed instructions can be found [here.](https://www.docusign.com.au/p/APIGuide/Content/Introduction+Changes/Integrator%20Keys.htm)